# If $p,q,r$ are prime numbers such that $p\mid(q-1)$ and $pq\mid(r+1)$, is $p$ necessarily equal to $2$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $p,q,r$ be three prime numbers such that $p\mid(q-1)$, $p\mid(r+1)$, $q\mid(r+1)$. Can we conclude that $p=2$?

**My try**: Clearly, $q,r \ne 2$. We have $q=kp+1$ for some $k$ and $r+1=spq$ for some $s$.
So $r+1=sp(kp+1)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No! consider $p = 5, q = 11$ and $r = 109$.

Answer (score 1):

Counterexample:
$$p=3,\quad q=7,\quad r=41.$$

Comment: Sorry, this answer (slightly "better" than the accepted one because the numbers are smaller)  was ready to type as soon as I read the question, but I have been busy meanwhile.